# What software can I use to voice chat with my players while also being able to reproduce SFX comfortably?

Tags: tools, online-roleplaying, sound-effects

I'm hosting an online Role Playing Game through Maptool and I need to be able to speak through the microphone while at the same time playing sounds from a soundboard without having to switch the capturing device (from microphone to stereo mix) every time I do this.

Comment: Although we do field questions for tools specific to roleplaying games, this is a question that has no special need for roleplaying expertise, and is therefore off topic here. However, you can ask for software recommendations at the [softwarerecs.se] Stack.

Comment: "Tools and equipment used while playing table-top RPGs (including running them online"

I thought this question was well within this category

Comment: It fits the tag, but it must first fit the site. What you'll be using the software for isn't an essential part of the problem, and what remains is not in need of RPG expertise. We're not experts in combining sound board software, voice chat, and sound mixers.

Comment: Well then, fair enough.

Comment: Although (and sorry for doubleposting) maybe another GM sorted that out and could share his experience.

Comment: Sorry about that! On the plus side, SoftwareRecs.SE should have much better help for this than we would.